# SignXML verification started to fail as of November 2022 - 'Signature verification failed: bad signature'

Tags: python-3.x, xml, validation, saml

We use a python solution using SignXML and LXML - latest versions to run a production SSO solution. We are the Service Provider. We do receive a sign XML assertions when a user tries to access our system.

All worked fine until November 17, 2022. Since then every request gets 'Signature verification failed: bad signature'.

But I think just SignXML causing this issue.
As part of the CI/CD we generate integration tests on each deployment, and our tests work and successfully.
We don't have our client's private key, so we can't replicate the issue. But each request from them is invalid.
Any ideas? I've looked at changes of SignXML https://pypi.org/project/signxml but nothing. Thanks!

I tried different python versions, 3.9, 3.10, 3.11, but I get the same behavior. I tried different methods but no fix.
Our validation method:

```
def validate_saml_assertion(saml_value, trusted_cert, tenant_prefix):   
    root = etree.fromstring(saml_value)
    
signature_node = root.findall("Signature", namespaces={None: "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"})
    
cert_on_file = validate_fingerprint(cert_from_xml, trusted_cert, tenant_prefix)
    
return XMLVerifier().verify(saml_value, x509_cert=cert_on_file).signed_xml
```

Different python versions, different libraries versions.
When we pin older dependencies versions, it still works.

We pinned these versions:
lxml==4.9.0 signxml==2.9.0 pyjwt==2.4.0 cryptography==37.0.2

Comment: Question is not a [mcve]. `findall` returns a list of elements but a single node is needed.

Comment: You need to do some troubleshooting and debugging. Can you verify the signature of the assertion that you received using one of the online saml tools? Some of them will specify whether the digest is failing or the signature. If that part is fine, you'll need to determine what is failing on your end. Is it the XML signature for sure or is it some other part of the verification that's failing? Did they change the certificate that is used to sign the assertion? If so, you need to update the certificate that you verifying it against. It could be any number of issues but verify with an online tool